# Node.js npm run dev throws missing module error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-run

I'm running ubuntu on Virtual Machine on a windows computer; I have node.js and npm installed globally (node version 10.6.0; npm version 6.4.1). I cloned a React app from our internal bitbucket repo, checked out to a branch and created a new branch from that; the app is supposed to run by 'npm run dev' but when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
  throw err;
  ^

   Error: Cannot find module 'braces'
```

When I install module 'braces', and try 'npm run dev' it gives missing module of some other module and so on. I was told by one of the developers that I need to be running npm locally and not globally (which is how I have it in my case); I tried uninstalling node.js and npm but the system won't uninstall it. Do i need to do the uninstall from root (by doing sudo -i, going to root and uninstalling)? Also, I need node.js version 10.6.0 and npm version 6.4.1 which is needed to run my other node.js/graphQL APIs - how do I make sure that I install those exact versions, after uninstalling node.js and npm from root?

Following is debug info from debug log:

```
  1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' 
   ]
   2 info using npm@6.4.1
   3 info using node@v10.6.0
   4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
   5 info lifecycle abcms@1.0.2~predev: abcms@1.0.2
   6 info lifecycle abcms@1.0.2~dev: abcms@1.0.2
   7 verbose lifecycle abcms@1.0.2~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
   8 verbose lifecycle abcms@1.0.2~dev: PATH: 
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp- 
       bin:/home/usname123/Documents/DEV/uppperFolder/
      abcms/node_modules/.bin:/home/rv7 

       94a/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/js:/home/usname123/.local/
       bin:/home/usn 
       ame123/bin:/home/usname123/.local/bin:/var/opt/SoapUI- 

        5.2.1/bin:/var/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_77/bin:/usr/
        local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin 
    :/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
    9 verbose lifecycle abcms@1.0.2~dev: CWD: 
    /home/rv794a/Documents/DEV/upperFolder/abcms
      10 silly lifecycle abcms@1.0.2~dev: Args: 
    [ '-c', 'webpack-dev-server -- 
      mode development --open' ]
    11 silly lifecycle abcms@1.0.2~dev: Returned: code: 1 signal: null
    12 info lifecycle abcms@1.0.2~dev: Failed to exec dev script
     13 verbose stack Error: abcms@1.0.2 dev: `webpack-dev-server --mode 
    development --open`
   13 verbose stack Exit status 1
   13 verbose stack at EventEmitter.<anonymous> 
   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm- 
    lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
   13 verbose stack at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
   13 verbose stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm- 
    lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
   13 verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
   13 verbose stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
   13 verbose stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
    (internal/child_process.js:248:5)
   14 verbose pkgid abcms@1.0.2
   15 verbose cwd /home/usname123/Documents/DEV/upperFolder/abcms
   16 verbose Linux 4.4.0-159-generic
   17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
   18 verbose node v10.6.0
   19 verbose npm v6.4.1
   20 error code ELIFECYCLE
   21 error errno 1
   22 error abcms@1.0.2 dev: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open`
   22 error Exit status 1
   23 error Failed at the abcms@1.0.2 dev script.
   23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
    additional logging output above.
   24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: do you have a `package.json`

Comment: Yes I do -  and it has "scripts":{"dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"}

Comment: Does it have dependencies listed too?

Comment: Yes - it has all the dependencies listed out; it's not the package.json that is the problem; as per the developer who developed that react app, I need to have npm running locally not globally; here's my thinking on this and pls. correct me if i'm wrong: I will go to root in ubuntu and uninstall node.js and npm; then I'll install node.js outside of root; then I'll install nvm and then locally install npm in the branch that I created; ----> would this approach work?

Comment: r u using webpack